# A C++ function that tests if the C string ends with a suffix

Tags: c++, string, function

```
bool endsWith(const char* str, const char* suffix)
```

Tests if the C string str ends with the specified suffix, the C string suffix.

Examples:

```
endsWith("hot dog", "dog")        // Should return true
endsWith("hot dog", "cat")        // Should return false
endsWith("hot dog", "doggle")     // Should return false
```

I have:

```
bool endsWith(const char* str, const char* suffix){
if(strstr(str, suffix)==(strlen(str)-strlen(suffix)))
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Comment: `strstr` returns a pointer, not an integer.

Comment: Please don't write your questions with invisible ink.

Comment: Would you consider `std::regex` or `std::search`?

Comment: This will fail (false negative) if the suffix occurs *elsewhere* in `str`. Are you familiar with `strcmp`?

Comment: can just use: `size_t str_len = strlen(str), suffix_len = strlen(suffix); return str_len >= suffix_len && strcmp(str + str_len - suffix_len, suffix) == 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution not using `std::string` could be this:

```
bool strendswith(const char* str, const char* suffix)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    int suffixlen = strlen(suffix);
    if(suffixlen > len)
    {
        return false;
    }

    str += (len - suffixlen);
    return strcmp(str, suffix) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really ask a question, but you mentioned a C++ function, so:

```
bool endsWith(std::string str, std::string suffix)
{
  if (str.length() < suffix.length())
    return false;

  return str.substr(str.length() - suffix.length()) == suffix;
}
```

Comment: You would ideally accept the parameters by `const` reference and use [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) to avoid the temporary from `substr`.